# How to add elements in a Array?

Tags: arrays, typescript

I am trying to add elements in an Array in Typescrypt with the push method, but it does not seem to work. the array remains empty. This is my code:

```
         list: Array<int> = Array(10)
         for(let x = 0; x <= 10; x++) {
                    list.push(x)
         }
```

someone got the same problem?

Comment: That code shouldn't compile, int isn't a keyword in typescript (number is). I also assume that list is defined as a class member and the for-loop is done somewhere else? Doesn't make sense otherwise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your case you can do :

```
     list: Array<number> = [];
     for(let x = 0; x <= 10; x++) {
          list.push(x)
     }
```

or

```
     list: Array<number> = Array(10)
     for(let x = 0; x <= 10; x++) {
          list[x];
     }
```

Explanation on your error :

`Array(10)` already creates an array with 10 "empty" elements.

if you use `push` on it, you will actually get your elements pushed, but in the 11th to the 20th position.

The 1st to the 10th ranks stay empty (and will return `undefined` if you try to get their value them)

Comment: moreover, as MohanaRajesh noticed, you use `int` instead of `number`

Comment: I know int does not exists I changed this in stackoverflow, not in my IDE. The datatype is acctually a more complicated datatype, but can't share that on the internet. Cause that will expose what I am working on. ;)

Answer (score 2):

So a few things to note:

- There's no `int` type in TypeScript, since JavaScript has only one number type, the corresponding TypeScript type is called `number`.
- You shouldn't use `Array(n)` (or the array constructor in general) to create an array, there's a lot of information about why that is (primarily, it creates what's called a sparse array, with a length property but no elements), but you should generally use `[]` to create a new array. All arrays in JavaScript are dynamic anyway, so the `10` you pass has no meaning.
- You should never define variables without declaring them with `const`, `let` or `var`.

Combining the points above, here's how your code should look like for this case

```
const list: number[] /* or Array<number> */ = []
for(let x = 0; x <= 10; x++) {
  list.push(x)
}
```

Comment: I know int does not exists I changed this in stackoverflow, not in my IDE. The datatype is acctually a more complicated datatype, but can't share that on the internet. Cause that will expose what I am working on. ;)

Comment: @HarryStylesheet You can't ask a question with code that doesn't compile and is not equivalent to the code you actually have, and expect helpful answers.

Answer (score 1):

int type is not available in typescript use number instead of int

```
let list: Array<number> =  Array(10);
for (let x = 0; x <= 10; x++) {
  list.push(x)
}
```

above code is pushing the value to array but this will return

```
[undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

to fix this please change code to

```
let list: Array<number> =  Array();
for (let x = 0; x <= 10; x++) {
  list[x] = x;
}
```

this will return `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]`

Comment: I know int does not exists I changed this in stackoverflow, not in my IDE. The datatype is acctually a more complicated datatype, but can't share that on the internet. Cause that will expose what I am working on. ;)